# Preciso incluir classes quando fazer herança?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Seguinte.

Quando eu quero usar alguma coisa, por exemplo, no index, eu quero puxar uma classe pra fazer um objeto, certo?

Imagine que a classe esteja assim:

```
<?php
class Testando{
   //Meu codigo aqui
}
?>
```

Ai, tenho meu index:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
             require'Testando.class.phg';
             $Teste = new Testando;
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Ai agora, tenho minha segunda class, vamos supor.. :

```
<?php
   //Aqui eu não precisaria de um require/include da class Testando?
   class EuTestei extends Testando {
       //Meu codigo aqui
   }
?>
```

Ali, onde comentei, na segunda class, não precisaria de include/require? Pôs aqui, testando, ela não da erro. Mas como ela acha essa classe?

Comment: Você está utilizando namespace? caso esteja utilizando autoload não é necessário dar o include/require..

Comment: autoload eu uso, mas não entendo, como aquela class extende a outra, sendo que não usei require.

Comment: Se este segundo arquivo também foi incluído no `index.php`, o PHP acha a classe pois ela foi carregada também no `index.php` através do primeiro `require`. Quando você faz o `require` ou `include`, para o PHP é como se todos os códigos estivessem escritos no mesmo arquivo, então a classe `Testando` estaria implementada antes da classe `EuTestei`, por isso funciona. Se no `index.php` você der `require` apenas do segundo arquivo, então sim, você precisará dar o `require` do primeiro onde você comentou.

Comment: Recomendo você a estudar e entender como funciona e pra que serve o autoload, pois ele já faz o carregamento completo de todas as classes, e onde você da um new no objeto ali já tem todas as classes do sistema carregadas.

Comment: Entendi, Anderson, se quiser por a resposta, ai marco como aceita!

Comment: Obrigado também Drik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos supor que temos três arquivos: dois com as definições das classes e outro que será o código a ser executado.

**Person.php**

```
<?php

class Person
{
    public $firstname;
    public $lastname;
}
```

**User.php**

```
<?php

class User extends Person
{
    public $username;
    public $password;
}
```

Perceba que a classe `User` estende a classe `Person`. Se no arquivo **index.php** fizermos algo como:

```
<?php

require "Person.php";
require "User.php";

$user = new User();
$user->firstname = "Anderson";
$user->lastname = "Woss";
```

Para o PHP, o arquivo executado seria basicamente:

```
<?php

// require "Person.php";
class Person
{
    public $firstname;
    public $lastname;
}


// require "User.php";
class User extends Person
{
    public $username;
    public $password;
}

$user = new User();
$user->firstname = "Anderson";
$user->lastname = "Woss";
```

E como todas as classes estão definidas funcionará perfeitamente, mesmo que no arquivo **User.php** não tenhamos incluído o arquivo **Person.php**, pois no final, tudo foi interpretado como um arquivo só.

O que a função de *autoload* faz é basicamente isso: incluir todas as dependências no arquivo **index.php**, pois assim elas estarão definidas em todos os arquivos da aplicação - partindo da consideração que a aplicação é sempre executada sobre o arquivo **index.php**.